# Understanding Emacs macro and org mode tikz behavior

Tags: latex, elisp-macros

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7467870/org-mode-html-export) discussion, and the last response gives this code:

```
#+TITLE: Test
#+AUTHOR: Blah
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [american]
#
# Setup tikz package for both LaTeX and HTML export:
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}
#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex+ :packages '(("" "tikz"))
#
#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex+ :exports results

* One Diamond

#+name: diamond
#+header: :file (by-backend (latex "diamond.tikz") (t "diamond.svg"))
#+begin_src latex :results raw file
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (1,0) -- (0,1) -- (-1,0) -- (0,-1) -- cycle;
    % \node at (0,0) {\(x_i\)};
  \end{tikzpicture}
#+end_src

#+caption: A diamond.
#+attr_latex: :float t :width ""
#+results: diamond

* COMMENT setup

#+name: setup
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :results silent :exports none
  ;; (setq org-babel-latex-htlatex "htlatex")
  (defmacro by-backend (&rest body)
    `(case (if (boundp 'backend) (org-export-backend-name backend) nil) ,@body))
#+end_src

# Local variables:
# eval: (org-sbe "setup")
# End:
```

First, the local variable call to elisp block `setup` doesn't seem to work. But then I don't really understand what `by-backend` is doing. Where can I learn about such a macro and why is it used in this situation? Also, why is so much placed in the org-mode header, i.e., what exactly are these doing?

```
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [american]
#
# Setup tikz package for both LaTeX and HTML export:
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{tikz}
#+PROPERTY: header-args:latex+ :packages '(("" "tikz"))
#
```

I've seen TikZ code like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
```

and org-mode doesn't seem to like it. Where and how would it be utilized? Basically, I'm trying to put together a comprehensive tutorial on TikZ in org-mode. I'm seeing lots of one-off tunneling. Need a good tutorial, I'd say. . . .

Comment: I don't know which version of org-mode above code was written for: `by-backend` is seemingly used for swiching the export behaviour according to chosen backends (latex vs. html e.g.). in org-mode 9 such a functionality is provided by `org-export-current-backend`.

Comment: `#+LATEX_CLASS:` will invoke an Org template named `"article"`, this template defines `documentclass` and some other headers. `#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS:` will populate the part of the template related to `documentclass`. `#+LATEX_HEADER:` will also populate the same template, but will insert any LaTeX code before `documentclass` and `\begin{document}`. You don't have to use `tikz` document class (unless your entire work is in tikz, in which case you don't really need Org).